# Find connected branches from list of line segments

Tags: python, geometry, shapely, line-segment

**Problem**

I have a list of line segments:

```
exampleLineSegments = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(4,7),(8,7)]
```

These segments include the indices of the corresponding point in a separate array.

From this sublist, one can see that there is a branching point (4). So three different branches are emerging from this branching point. 
(In other, more specific problems, there might be / are multiple branching points for *n* branches.)

**Target**

My target is to get a dictionary including information about the existing branches, so e.g.:

```
result = { branch_1: [1,2,3,4],
           branch_2: [4,5,6],
           branch_3: [4,7,8]}
```

**Current state of work/problems**

Currently, I am identifying the branch points first by setting up a dictionary for each point and checking for each entry if there are more than 2 neighbor points found. This means that there is a branching point.

Afterwards I am crawling through all points emerging from these branch points, checking for successors etc.

In these functions, there are a some *for loops* and generally an intensive "crawling". This is not the cleanest solution and if the number of points increasing, the performance is not so good either.

**Question**

What is the best / fastest / most performant way to achieve the target in this case?

Comment: does it only contain one branching point?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. In this example case only one branching point is existing. In other problems, multiple branching points can exist

Comment: ok, I got it. I'm work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve it by following steps:

1. use a `neighbors` dict to store the graph
2. find all branch points, which neighbors count > 2
3. start from every branch point, and use [dfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to find all the paths

```
from collections import defaultdict
def find_branch_paths(exampleLineSegments):
    # use dict to store the graph
    neighbors = defaultdict(list)
    for p1, p2 in exampleLineSegments:
        neighbors[p1].append(p2)
        neighbors[p2].append(p1)

    # find all branch points
    branch_points = [k for k, v in neighbors.items() if len(v) > 2]

    res = []

    def dfs(cur, prev, path):
        # reach the leaf
        if len(neighbors[cur]) == 1:
            res.append(path)
            return
        for neighbor in neighbors[cur]:
            if neighbor != prev:
                dfs(neighbor, cur, path + [neighbor])

    # start from all the branch points
    for branch_point in branch_points:
        dfs(branch_point, None, [branch_point])

    return res
```

update an `iteration` version, for big data, which may cause `a recursion depth problem`:

```
def find_branch_paths(exampleLineSegments):
    # use dict to store the graph
    neighbors = defaultdict(list)
    for p1, p2 in exampleLineSegments:
        neighbors[p1].append(p2)
        neighbors[p2].append(p1)

    # find all branch points
    branch_points = [k for k, v in neighbors.items() if len(v) > 2]

    res = []
    # iteration way to dfs
    stack = [(bp, None, [bp]) for bp in branch_points]
    while stack:
        cur, prev, path = stack.pop()

        if len(neighbors[cur]) == 1 or (prev and cur in branch_points):
            res.append(path)
            continue

        for neighbor in neighbors[cur]:
            if neighbor != prev:
                stack.append((neighbor, cur, path + [neighbor]))

    return res
```

test and output:

```
print(find_branch_paths([(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (4, 7), (8, 7)]))
# output: 
# [[4, 3, 2, 1], [4, 5, 6], [4, 7, 8]]
```

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

UPDATE: if there are many branch points, the path will grow exponentially. So if you only want distinct segments, you can end the path when encounter another branch point.

change this line
`if len(neighbors[cur]) == 1:`
to
`if len(neighbors[cur]) == 1 or (prev and cur in branch_points):`

Comment: hi @recnac , first: Thank you very  very much. This code looks so clean also works fine (and is really fast!). Unfortunately, i was moving to my largest problem and encountered a recursion depth problem (never had one before). Is there a good workaround to avoid this error?      


 File "", line 32, in dfs
    if len(neighbors[cur]) == 1 or (prev and cur in branch_points):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison


I googled and found something like 
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(3000)

But is there a "smarter" solution?

Comment: how large of your data? If path length is longer than maximum recursion depth, you can use `iteration` version instead of `recursion` version. Or implement your own `stack` instead of using system function stack.

Comment: if you data is large, you only can record distinct path like I said above.

Comment: I will write a `iteration` version for you.

Comment: try the `iteration` version : )  @BennyS

Comment: That is so awesome! It works, also without the "sys solution". Thank you very very much recnac! I will try it more extensive next week :)